# Why this isn't working ? Php Array Auto Replace Values and short Array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I need to select a rand value in the array removed and short the array i came out whit this small code but it keeps in an infinite loop but this is the weird look

```
<?php

$array=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
$count=count($array);

for ($il=1;$il<=$count;$il++){
$array_value=array_rand($array, 1); 
$array_value_key = array_search($array_value, $array);
$array_key_last=array_key_last($array);

for($if=0;$if<=$array_key_last;$if++){

if ($if==$array_value_key){

    for($ia=$array_value_key;$ia<=$array_key_last;$ia++){
        
        if ($ia<$array_key_last){
            $ian=$ia+1;
            $array[$ia]=$array[$ian];
            }else{
                unset($array[$ia]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

print_r($array);
    
 }
    ?>
```

there the output can be different each time likes this but never ends

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 9
    [8] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 9
    [7] => 0
)
^C
```

and i have to break it but as you can see in the first loop work as expected removes the number 4 and in the second loop removes the number 1 but don't finish the third loop

I have reviewed many times and get in to the conclusion of the problem it is on the line

```
$array[$ia]=$array[$ian];
```

if i add a echo here get printing a number it self to the infinity why?

```
$array[$ia]=$array[$ian];
echo $array[$ia],"\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is not in one line. It takes a few commands to interact:

1. `array_rand` returns the key of the element not the value
2. `array_search` returns (bool)false if it doesn't find the value (because of 1 this can happen)
3. You use `$array_value_key` to start a for loop. Because of 2 it can be (bool)false.
4. When you increment a boolean, it does not change. I.e. your `$ia++` does nothing.
5. That's why `$ia<=$array_key_last` will never turn false and your loop runs forever.

Comment: then array_search it is unnecessary that's it ! thank you I could be there like weeks whit out realized hahaha ! is done ! and work as expected, just place the rand on the $array_value_key variable and it works !